# How to wrap response - Response returns null

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using the code snippet below I get an object back from my AWS S3 bucket.
Now, I would like to modify the object on the fly within some other method, therefor I need to be able to return the response of the method below.

However, since I have a using clause, the `GetResponseObject` gets disposed, which essentially returns `null`.

I read in [Work with an Amazon S3 response stream after response has been disposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6214185/1405376) that I should return the response. However if I return the response it returns `null` in the calling method.

Maybe you could explain the three [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6214185/1405376) steps with some code snippets? That would be very helpful.

1. Return Response
2. Wrap the Stream
3. Callback

At this point I don't quiet understand why my approach of returning `response` as shown below results in `response` being `null`.

```
public GetObjectResponse GetFile(string keyName)
{
    using (client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
    {
        GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = keyName
        };

        using (GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request))
            using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Reader: " + reader.ReadToEnd());
                    Console.WriteLine("Stream: " + responseStream);
                    return response;
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply move `response` out of the `using` blocks?  Declare it before the other 2 `using` and then return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `return response;`, one of the things that occurs before control can pass to the calling function is all `using` blocks must be finished.  In your case, this means `reader`, `responseStream`, `response`, and `client` are all disposed.  Even if you did get a variable returned, it'd be useless since you can't perform any operations on a disposed object.

To fix this, simply move

```
using (GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request))
```

to

```
GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request);
```

Furthermore, I'd very much assume the returned stream from S3 to be a non-seekable stream, meaning once you've called `ReadToEnd()` on it, you won't be able to do much with it.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been helpful if you added the result of the Console.WriteLine's. I assume you see the result of client.GetObject(request) on the first line.

Problem is that you are reading the stream: reader.ReadToEnd(). This will set the position of the stream at the end of the stream.

When you want to return response there are no more bytes in the stream, and so null is returned.

If you remove the Console.WriteLine's you should get a response that is not null.